# ng-grid tabbing in editable cells cycle on last row

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-grid

When tabbing through the grids editable cells, and tabbing gets to the last row it continues to cycle through the last row instead of exiting the grid and going onto the next form item.

Not Ideal, but at the very least I would think the tabbing should loop back to the first row of the grid.

So my question is what is the correct behavior when tabbing through a grid control like ng-grid? Or do I just have something configured incorrectly?

Here's a plunker to demonstrate the issue. Just click into the first editable cell and start tabbing through. [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/lNXNww?p=preview)